# Про кодировку в строке

Tags: java, строки, кодировка, resourcebundle

Есть задача написать программу на двух языках, на английском и русском. Я использую Bundle для реализации этой цели. Все идет отлично, пока не начинаю выводить строку на русском языке, он выводит либо вопросительные знаки, либо краказябры на подобии таких "Ïðèâåò, ýòîé ìîé òåêñò".

Как можно изменить кодировку строки?

Такой метод

```
System.out.println(new String(bundleRU.getString("somevalue").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

не работает.

А так вот он *код*

```
Locale ru = new Locale("ru", "RU");
ResourceBundle bundleRU = ResourceBundle.getBundle("minoroop/resources", ru);
System.out.println(new String(bundleRU.getString("somevalue").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

и *resources_ru.properties*

```
somevalue=Привет, этой мой текст
```

Что я делаю не так?

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Какая кодировка у `resources_ru.properties`? Подозреваю что не utf-8. Подозреваю что cp1251.

Comment: А как поменять кодировку у файла .properties? Я использую IntelliJ